# double ended list

Tags: c++, linked-list

The following code stops working, shows an empty screen, shows a number, and then prints an error message that code stopped working.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Link{
public:
  long ddata;
  Link *next;
  Link(long d){
    ddata=d;
  }
  void displaylin(){
    cout<<ddata<<"  "<<endl;
  }
};

class firstlast{
private :
  Link *first;
  Link * last;
public:
  firstlast(){
    first=NULL;
    last=NULL;
  }
  bool empthy(){
    return (first==NULL);
  }
  void insertfirst(long dd){
    Link *newlink=new Link(dd);
    if (empthy())
      last=newlink;
    newlink->next=first;
    first=newlink;
  }
  void insertlast(long dd){
    Link *newlink=new Link(dd);
    if ((empthy()))
      first=newlink;
    else
      last->next=newlink;
    newlink=last;
  }
  long deletefirst(){    //delete first link
    long temp=first->ddata;
    if (first->next==NULL)//only one item
      last=NULL;
    first=first->next;
    return temp;
  }
  void displayList(){
    cout<<"first -> last   "<<endl;
    Link *current=first;
    while(current!=NULL){
      current->displaylin();
      current=current->next;
    }
  }
};

int main(){
  firstlast *fl=new firstlast();
  fl->insertfirst(22);
  fl->insertfirst(44);
  fl->insertfirst(66);
  fl->insertlast(33);
  fl->insertlast(88);
  fl->insertlast(100);
  fl->deletefirst();
  fl->displayList();
  return 0;
}
```

I think somewhere is is overflow, but I can't find where. [IDE One shows the output of my program.](http://www.ideone.com/RZPnk)

Comment: Your problem description is really hard to understand. Could you edit your question with exactly what output you are getting? If the code is blowing up, did you use a debugger to try to identify exactly where it is blowing up?

Comment: i have added link,where is  output given

Comment: Not good enough. Please make sure your question is complete without external links, especially ones that aren't clickable. You want to give the maximum of information in your question so that people can see right away what your problem is. If you require people to go look through links to help you, you're losing out on a good part of the audience here.

Comment: i  have problem that when i run this code,imagine how it happens,black command line window appear,shows me this output 44  
22  
100   and stops working  by  showing another windows form  which usually  appear in case of some bugs

Comment: And while you're add it, format the code so it's readable.

Comment: Edit your question to add that information as clearly as you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line in `insertlast(long)`:

```
newlink=last;
```

It should be:

```
last=newlink;
```

With that change, [the output](http://www.ideone.com/T8PpS) becomes:

```
first -> last   
44  
22  
33  
88  
100
```

**EDIT:** As @Jared pointed out, your code suffers from memory leaks. This happens whenever you allocate heap memory with `new` or `malloc` but do not free it with the corresponding "free" function.

It is important that each pointer returned by `new` be freed exactly once by `delete`. If you fail to call `delete`, then your program leaks memory. If you call `delete` more than once to "double free" a region, then your program invokes Undefined Behavior.

In this code:

```
  long deletefirst(){    //delete first link
    long temp=first->ddata;
    if (first->next==NULL)//only one item
      last=NULL;
    first=first->next;
    return temp;
  }
```

notice that `first=first->next;` makes you lose the pointer to a piece of dynamically-allocated memory. Remember that `first` was set to the result of `new`, so you need to `delete first` before overwriting `first` with a pointer to a different region of dynamically-allocated memory.

Also, you need to add to your class:

1. A destructor to free all memory that wasn't freed through calls to `deletefirst()`.
2. A copy constructor to make a deep copy of `firstlast` instances.
3. An overload of the assignment operator, `operator=(const firstlast& fl)`, that also makes a deep copy.

Answer (score 1):

First off, your insertLast method results in a memory leak, as you never actually connect the next pointers of the newly-created Links to anything. You simply reassign the local pointer newlink, which goes out of scope immediately afterward. Subsequent insertLast calls leave memory out in space. This might also be causing the error to be printed.

Second, your deleteFirst method doesn't actually delete anything, but leaves a Link allocated with new out in memory with nothing pointing to it anymore. Another memory leak.

Comment: how can i avoid it?i mean  second  case

Comment: One way you can do it is create a temporary Link* and initialize it to first. Then, once you have moved first to the next node, explicitly call delete on that temporary Link* you created. The point is that you have to actually call delete on that Link object, since you created it with the new keyword.